# Adding specified element from many rows JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got table structure like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price"></td>
         (...)
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price"></td>
         (...)
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    (...)
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price"></td>
         (...)
        <td></td>
    </tr>       
</tbody>
```

I just want to pull every td price value and sum it up. At the end i just need an variable with total value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate over the `td` elements and make sure you use `parseInt` to avoid concatenating strings rather than summing

```js
var sum = 0;
$('td.price').each(function(){
sum += parseInt($(this).text());
});
document.write('Sum is ' + sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">5</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">10</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">20</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>       
</tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map()` and reducing it to the sum:

```
var sum = $('td.price').map(function () {
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10)
}).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

```js
var sum = $('td.price').map(function () {
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10);
}).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">5</td>
         (...)
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">10</td>
         (...)
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    (...)
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="price">20</td>
         (...)
        <td></td>
    </tr>       
</tbody>
  <table>
```